# How to import another language in PNAS document?

Tags: languages, pnas

I'm trying to create new document with the PNAS template, but i would like to use another language (Macedonian). I'm using: `\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{pnas-new}` and I am getting errors when i type

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[macedonian]{babel}
```

The error is: 
**LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.**

Here is the link of the template and the document: [PNAS document](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wrndhzhxbnwd)

Please help me.
Thank you.

*PS: I'm VERY NEW at using Latex, and i need it for a college project.*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). It would be helpful to know *which* error messages you get. Also it would be nice if you could turn your code snippets into a [minimal (non-)working example (M(N)WE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. This will make it much easier for us -- the helpers to help you. Please do this by editing your question.

Comment: @StefanPinnow done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that PNAS supports languages other than English. Anyway, you should be able to get away with

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=macedonian}{babel}
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{pnas-new}
```

The error for a missing font can be solved by adding

```
\setboolean{displaywatermark}{false}
```

after the `\documentclass` line.

If you still want the watermark and to fix all fonts, the start of the document should be

```
% fix the missing bits in pnas-new
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=macedonian}{babel}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@lmodern.sty\endcsname{}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@helvet.sty\endcsname{}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@helvet.sty\endcsname{scaled}
% End startup fixes

\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside,lineno,main=macedonian]{pnas-new}

% fix the calls to lmss
\renewcommand{\titlefont}{\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{22pt}{24pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\dropcapfont}{\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{26pt}{28pt}\selectfont}

% fix for the big fonts
\usepackage{etoolbox,draftwatermark}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\sc@watermark}
  {\selectfont}
  {\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \SetWatermarkText{{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{bch}\bfseries DRAFT}}%
}
% End fixes
```

## A full example

Translations have been obtained via Google Translate, sorry if they're wrong.

I added some more fixes to accommodate other bits of information.

```
% fix the missing bits in pnas-new
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=macedonian}{babel}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@lmodern.sty\endcsname{}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@helvet.sty\endcsname{}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@helvet.sty\endcsname{scaled}
% End startup fixes

\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside,lineno,main=macedonian]{pnas-new}

% fix the calls to lmss
\renewcommand{\titlefont}{\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{22pt}{24pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\dropcapfont}{\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{26pt}{28pt}\selectfont}

% fix for the big fonts
\usepackage{etoolbox,draftwatermark}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\sc@watermark}
  {\selectfont}
  {\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
  {}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \SetWatermarkText{{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{bch}\bfseries DRAFT}}%
}
% for acknowledgments
\patchcmd{\showacknow}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}{Благодарност}{}{}
\renewcommand{\additionalelement}[1]{%
  \def\@additionalelement{#1}%
  \patchcmd\@additionalelement{Significance Statement}{Изјава за значење}{}{}%
}
\makeatother
% End fixes

\templatetype{pnasresearcharticle} % Choose template 
% {pnasresearcharticle} = Template for a two-column research article
% {pnasmathematics} = Template for a one-column mathematics article
% {pnasinvited} = Template for a PNAS invited submission

\title{Template for preparing your research report submission to PNAS using Overleaf}

% Use letters for affiliations, numbers to show equal authorship (if applicable) and to indicate the corresponding author
\author[a,c,1]{Автор Еден}
\author[b,1,2]{Автор Две} 
\author[a]{Автор Три}

\affil[a]{Припадност Еден}
\affil[b]{Припадност Две}
\affil[c]{Припадност Три}

% Please give the surname of the lead author for the running footer
\leadauthor{Еден} 

% Please add here a significance statement to explain the relevance of your work
\significancestatement{Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.}

% Please include corresponding author, author contribution and author declaration information
\authorcontributions{Ве молиме наведете детали за авторските придонеси овде.}
\authordeclaration{Ве молиме да го пријавите конфликт на интереси овде.}
\equalauthors{\textsuperscript{1}Автор Еден и Автор Две придонесоа подеднакво на оваа работа (отстранете ако не е применливо).}
\correspondingauthor{\textsuperscript{2}На кого треба да се однесува преписката. E-mail: author.two\@email.com}

% Keywords are not mandatory, but authors are strongly encouraged to provide them. If provided, please include two to five keywords, separated by the pipe symbol, e.g:
\keywords{Клучен збор 1 $|$ Клучен збор 2 $|$ Клучен збор 3 $|$ ...} 

\begin{abstract}
Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.
\end{abstract}

\dates{Овој ракопис беше составен на \today}
\doi{\url{www.pnas.org/cgi/doi/10.1073/pnas.XXXXXXXXXX}}

\begin{document}

% Optional adjustment to line up main text (after abstract) of first page with line numbers, when using both lineno and twocolumn options.
% You should only change this length when you've finalised the article contents.
\verticaladjustment{-2pt}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{shortarticle}}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{singlecolumn}}{\abscontentformatted}{\abscontent}}{}

% If your first paragraph (i.e. with the \dropcap) contains a list environment (quote, quotation, theorem, definition, enumerate, itemize...), the line after the list may have some extra indentation. If this is the case, add \parshape=0 to the end of the list environment.
\dropcap{П}араграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

\section*{Наслов}

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

\subsection*{Наслов}

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

\subsection*{Наслов}

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

Параграф текст на македонски јазик за да се испроба дали говново функционира некако аман веќе му ебам матер.

\showmatmethods % Display the Materials and Methods section

\acknow{Ве молиме, вклучете ги вашите признанија овде, поставени во еден став. Ве молиме не вклучувајте никакви признанија во Информативната поддршка или на друго место во ракописот.}

\showacknow % Display the acknowledgments section

% \pnasbreak splits and balances the columns before the references.
% If you see unexpected formatting errors, try commenting out this line
% as it can run into problems with floats and footnotes on the final page.
%\pnasbreak

% Bibliography
\bibliography{pnas-sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After adding your code, i'm getting this error: Font T2A/lmr/m/n/85.35826=larm5159 at 51.59pt not
 loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.122

Comment: It would be great if you are available to check the document from the link i've posted.

Comment: That's odd; I'd just answered a similar question on Overleaf support a couple of days ago. If you have set `main=macedonian` then your entire doc should be in Macedonian. Otherwise try instead `\PassOptionsToPackage{english,main=macedonian}{babel}` and where you still have English text, use `\selectlanguage{english}` or `\textenglatin{...}`. (also I changed your project's link in your question to a read-only link)

Comment: bah I meant `\textlatin{...}`

Comment: @LianTzeLim i guess you changed the document and left some comments. I tried to change the whole text in Macedonian and i removed the \selectlanguage{english} but it still does not work. I tried it here: https://www.overleaf.com/13129199fdhtjbzgpvdk#/50442714/

Comment: @Aleksandar That's due to the watermark; just add `\setboolean{displaywatermark}{false}` after the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: @egreg Yep I just added that too! Also commented out \maketitle temporarily as all the metadata has been commented out. Note that it's probably best to rename pnas-new.cls to pnas-new-macedonian.cls, and replace any English text like "Draft", "Significance Statement" etc with Macedonian equivalents so that the complete paper can be typeset correctly.

Comment: @egreg But after changing the language, i can not use the \maketitle and also the sections are not the same :/

Comment: Also, i can not type BOLD text...

Comment: @Aleksandar I added a more thorough set of fixes

Comment: @egreg how can i change the .cls file with Overleaf?

Comment: @Aleksandar You don't change the `.cls` file. Why should you? But, why do you need this class?

Comment: @egreg because my teacher said I have to process an article in Latex in PNAS format...

Comment: @Aleksandar I see no need to change the class file. If you want to have a translation for “draft”, then tell me what it's like in Macedonian and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your help. Very kind of you :)

Comment: @Aleksandar I added a full example, hoping it contains everything you need.